# kerberos client not generating log file

Tags: kerberos

I have a kerberos client and following is the config of that client for logging.

```
[logging]
  default = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
  admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log
  kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
```

however when I check the files to see the logs it doesn't exist.  Even if I try to authenticate with wrong username it shows the error message on console only.

> kinit -kt gaurang.shah.keytab gaurang.shah@ab.com
>
> kinit: Keytab contains no suitable keys for gaurang.shah@ab.com while getting
> initial credentials

Could someone please let me know what I need to do in so that all the error messages are redirected to log file. Also, is there any way to change verbose of the logs ?

Comment: What version of Kerberos?  Can we see the full syntax used to create the keytab?  What OS are you running on?

Comment: I am using Linux, issue is not with authentication with keytab, i have intentionally gave wrong principal name so that error is generated. Problem is this error is not being redirected to log file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This configuration is not intended for the client as you can see by the filenames. You are looking for `KRB5_TRACE=/path/to/file` env var. This works on MIT Kerberos only.

Comment: there is one minor issue. If i have to path to my home directory I am able to see the log file, however if I set the path to `/var/log/krb5_trace.log` it doesn't even create the file

Comment: @GaurangShah You cannot write to `/var/log` you aren't root. Try `$HOME/krb5.log`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using heimdal, try

```
[logging]
    default = 0-/FILE:/dev/stderr
    krb5 = 0-/FILE:/dev/stderr
```

Where the path after FILE: is the logfile you want (in this case spam to stderr)

The 0-/ means use log levels 0-7, so very verbose logging.

The default is 0-3 and that doesn't appear to change using the ENV setting (which only works on the krb5 library anyway)

For further information the correct man page to RTFM is `krb5_initlog` in section `3`